# paths to directory between double quotes, but unexpected token 'append' again

Tags: c#, python, exception, append, token

I'm new to C# and Python and I can't solve an issue trying to execute a Python script from C#. My problem is exactly the same posted at the following link:

[Unexpected token append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281491/unexpected-token-append)

I found an answer on another site where they suggest to wrap paths to directories in Python between double quotes. Well I fixed it, but the problem is still the same, "unexpected token 'append'".

My C# code is the following:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"/Users/alberto/Desktop/Csharp/test_corso/scacchi/scacchiera.py");

ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"/Users/alberto/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages");
paths.Add(@"/Users/alberto/anaconda3/lib/python3.7");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
```

my Python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pytz
import pandas as pd

chess=pd.read_csv("/Users/alberto/Desktop/Csharp/test_corso/scacchi/scacchiera.txt",names=['nome','colore','indice','stato','x','y'],header=None)

chess_occ=chess[chess['stato']=='ok']
chess_occ=chess_occ.drop_duplicates(['nome','colore','indice'],keep='last')
chess_tail=chess.tail(1)

chess_merge=pd.merge(chess_occ,chess_tail,on=['x','y'],suffixes=['','_'])
a=pd.merge(chess_merge,chess_tail,on=['nome','colore','indice'],how='outer',suffixes=['','_t'],indicator=True)
a=a[a['_merge']=='left_only']
a=a[['nome','colore','indice','stato','x','y','colore_']]

for i in a.index:
        if a['colore'][i]!=a['colore_'][i]:
                a['stato'][i]='ko'

b=pd.merge(chess,a,how='left',on=['nome','colore','indice'],suffixes=['','_new'])
b=b.drop(['x_new','y_new','colore_'],axis=1)

for i in b.index:
    if b['stato_new'][i]=='ko':
        b['stato'][i]='ko'

b=b.drop(['stato_new'],axis=1)
b.to_csv("/Users/alberto/Desktop/Csharp/test_corso/scacchi/scacchiera.txt",index=False,header=False)

occupati=b.drop_duplicates(['nome','colore','indice'],keep='last')
occupati=occupati[occupati['stato']=='ok']
occupati=occupati[['x','y']]
occupati.to_csv("/Users/alberto/Desktop/Csharp/test_corso/scacchi/occupati.txt",index=False,header=False)
        source.Execute(scope);
```

Where am I wrong? Thank you very much!
Bye, Gufus